# How to add unnamed uci section if not exist?

Tags: openwrt

I want to configure ipsec via uci (always ipsec[0]). Everything works correctly if ipsec section exists. I can modify ipsec using uci ipsec.@ipsec[0].type='tunnel'. But if ipsec section doesn't exist this command is not working. I want to add the ipsec section if not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found is to use a shell script

```sh
if ! uci -q show ipsec.@ipsec[0]
then
    uci add ipsec ipsec
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`uci show ipsec` will show config other than ipsec[0] also so condition will get false and you will end up with adding multiple config of ipsec[0] ipsec[1]
you can do this via below ways.

```
config ipsec
     option type 'tunnel'

type_present=`uci -q get ipsec.@ipsec[0]`
if [ "$type_present" = ""]; then
      uci add ipsec ipsec
      uci commit ipsec
fi
```

if you have only one config ipsec then you can name that config section

```
config ipsec 'my_ipsec' # my_ipsec is named config
```

and you can access it in better way

```
uci get ipsec.my_ipsec.type
```

use -q -> quite mode which will not through an error if entry not found and return blank string.